# Optimize async operation executed by rest for many users

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-threads, completable-future

in following code I have asynchronous method which is executed by rest by authenticated user. In this method I execute loop in which is checking periodically cache of new data.

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<List<Data>> pollData(Long previousMessageId, Long userId) throws InterruptedException {
    // check db at first, if there are new data no need go to loop and waiting
    List<Data> data = dataRepository.findByLastAndByUser(dataId, userId));

    data not found so jump to loop for some time
    if (data.size() == 0) {
        short c = 0;
        while (c < 100) {

            // check if some new data added or not, if yes break loop
            if (cache.getIfPresent(userId) != null) {
                break;
            }
            c++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("SEQUENCE:  " + c + " in " +  Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

        // check database on the end of loop or after break from loop
        data = dataRepository.findByLastAndByUser(dataId, userId);
    }

    // clear data for that recipient and return result
    cache.clear(userId);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(data);
}
```

and executor bean:

```
@Bean
public Executor asyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

I execute this checking in separate thread for every request because these data are different for each user.

I need to optimize this code for many users (about 10k active users). In current state it doesn't work well because where there is more requests, these requests are waiting for some new free thread, and every another request takes very long time (5 min instead of 100 sec for example).

Can you help me improve it? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1):

In case there are no other concurrent calls to the pollData method, it takes at most ~100s.

The parameter maxPoolSize defines the maximum number of thread that can run concurrently your @Asynch method.

So  (number of users * execution time) / number of threads = 10K*100/2 = 500K[s].

I haven't completely understood the goal you want to reach with this method, but I suggest you to review the design of this functionality.

(For example take a look at spring cache, @evict,...)

(Notice that, in case you have multiple @async, you can bind the pool configuration with the @Asynch method by adding the name to the annotations @Bean("Pool1") and @Asynch("Pool1")).

Comment: goal is react to new data "immediately". So when one user call pollData, his request is waiting for new data, and when another user send data in his request, notification about new data in db is saved in cache. This is reason why I am checking it in loop. I am not very good in multithreading so I will be grateful for concrete answer with example what should I change.

Comment: Consider sending notification about new Data without the polling. 
When a user send data you retrieve all the users listening/waiting for those data and you notify them.

Comment: but which technology should I use for that notification? we are considering about rest which hasn't problem with firewalls and older browsers. Websockets we have as last choice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you want to do.
But I think obviously it fill quickly your pool of thread.

I think you should try to use message broker or something like this.

Instead of trying to respond to request by waiting something new append, you should connect your clients with AMQP, WebSocket, Webhook... etc... On your server, when you detect new informations, you notify your clients.

So you don't need to occupy one thread by client.

Comment: But I have same answer to you which technology should I use for that notification? we are considering about rest which hasn't problem with firewalls and older browsers. Websockets we have as last choice. With AMQP i have no experience so I should learn about it, can you provide example how should is works with client?

Comment: For AMQP, you can use Apache Paho for browser client.
For websocket, you can use Spring-Websocket that supports long polling (http) for older clients.
Webhooks are not applicable to browser client.
You can still simply do polling. Each client send request each 5 seconds, and the server respond instantly without Thread.sleep.

Comment: I can't tell you preciselly which technology use. There are several technologies applicable to your use case. For message broker, there is spring-websocket, rabbitMQ, activeMQ, kafka... etc..

Comment: Hi, so we decide to use websockets for that communication.  We think about following solition:
websocket channel will provide just notifications, so when some user send new data by post rest, notification will sent recipients by websockets which cause these clients create get requests

can you tell me what do you think about this solution?

Comment: I think this solution will work.
But I think it's a easier approach to set the data in the notification rather than make a GET request. It's a webservice less to make.

Comment: I think I helped you a bit, I little upvote please :P